# How to perform another method after finishing a method using completion block in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, completion-block

I have two methods. I want to execute one after finishing task of first one. How can i do this?

Comment: put some code brother

Comment: Call your second method the line before returning first method completion handler

Comment: @SivajeeBattina please show me some code, i am weak in completion handler.

Comment: func doSomething(flag:Bool, completionHandler:(success:Bool) -> Void) {
//Here you need to call your second method
self.secondMethod()
    completionHandler(success:true)
}

func secondMethod(){

}

Answer (score 7):

I assume you are looking for simple completion block solution, so this should be sufficient.

```
-(void)method1:(void (^ __nullable)(void))completion {
    NSLog(@"method1 started");
    //Do some stuff, then completion
    completion();
    NSLog(@"method1 ended");
}
-(void)method2{
    NSLog(@"method2 called");
}
```

Use like this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self method1:^{   //After method1 completion, method2 will be called
        [self method2];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like,

```
    [[manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

            NSLog(@"This is success!!!");

       //this is first method's completion blcok!

               // this is another method from completion of first
                    [self saveImages:^(BOOL isDone) {

                        // this is second method's completion

                    }];

               } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

            NSLog(@"failure : Error is : %@",error.localizedDescription);

          // this is completion of first method but with failure

        }]resume];
```

This is the simple example that how to manage it!! In this I have used [AFNEtworking's](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) method, so don't confuse with it!